# How to maintain CheckBox state across the activities

Tags: java, android, checkbox

How to `maintain` **CheckBox** `state` across the activities

I checked a CheckBox in `FirstActivity.java` but when i `move back` to **FirstActivity.java** from any other activity, say from `SecondActivity.java`..

Then, I am `not getting my CheckBox as check` which i checked earlier.

Using `onSaveInstanceState` & `onRestoreInstanceState`, see complete code below:-

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity {

    CheckBox cb1;
    Button btnNext;
    private boolean boolCheck1 = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        cb_cb1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb1);

        btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);

        // control status of body frame checkboxes
        cb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

           @Override
           public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(isChecked){

                }
            }
        });

        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
       savedInstanceState.putBoolean("Enable", cb1.isChecked());      
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        boolCheck1 = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("Enable");
    }
}
```

Comment: downvoting not an issue, but you should write reason as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best option is to use `sharedPreferences`.

In your activity where the `checkbox` is located, in your `onCreate()` put the following:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
Editor editor = pref.edit();
```

Then, in your `intent` to go to another activity, or "save" `button`, or whatever you want, use the following:

```
editor.putBoolean("checkbox", yourCheckbox.isChecked()); 
editor.commit(); // commit changes
```

Now, the setting is saved.

When you come back to your activity, use this in your `onCreate`:

```
if (pref.getBoolean("checkbox", false) == true){ //false is default value
yourCheckbox.setChecked(true); //it was checked
} else{
yourCheckbox.setChecked(false); //it was NOT checked
}
```

You can read more [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/).

Hope this helped

Answer (score 1):

Use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) or [SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) to store the value of check box and you can use it after fetching from `Database` or `SharedPreference`.

If you use `onSaveInstanceState` & `onRestoreInstanceState` all reference will clear when user close the app and the app is no longer in `Memory`.

- [Tutorial for SharedPreference](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFileBasedPersistence/article.html)
- [Tutorial for Database](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

To maintain state across activities you have to use SharedPreferences, or database. In your case [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) is the best option

You have used OnSavedInstance it will only save the instance until the activity is not destroyed i.e it stays on the stack.

Check [activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html) to understand more about when an activity is destroyed.

> For  each checkbox you can store its value in sharedPreference and on
>   onCreate() of you activity you should check the checkboxes according
>   to the sharedPreference values

Here is how you use shared prefs

```
SharedPreferences prefs= context.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", 0);
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("checkbox1", true);//true if checked 
        editor.commit();
      // get stored value , if no value is stored then assume its false
     prefs.getBoolean("checkbox1", false);
```